# Is it possible to "see" into the iterating collection of a C# foreach loop while debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, foreach

This is something I've often wanted to be able to do while debugging. If I have a line of code which computes a collection inside the header of a foreach loop:

```
foreach ( var item in someObject.GetItems( someParameter ) ) {
    ...
}
```

There doesn't seem to be anything I can hover over to get the computed set of items returned by `GetItems`, even though it was clearly computed and returned in order for the loop to be able to execute.

Just seems like something that would be obviously handy. Am I missing something? It's a pain to have to rewrite the code to store the list in a variable *just* so I can see it while debugging, especially if I discover a bug that isn't easily reproducible.

Comment: There are two distinct problems here:
(a) seeing the object being iterated over in the debugger, just as one can see the value of a local or object-level variable
(b) extracting the contents of a lazy collection during debugging.

Am I right in thinking that (a) is the one you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to just add the following expression to the watch window

```
someObject.GetItems(someParameter);
```

Hovering won't work for this scenario but explicitly adding it to the watch window will.  There is a lot of care taking in the code which evaluates expressions during hovering to not evaluate functions.  The logic being that functions are expensive, can deadlock the IDE and we don't want a hover operation to cause a deadlock.  The `GetItems` portion of this expression is a function evaluation and hence the EE refuses to evaluate it.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good workaround if I need to check it without restarting. Hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Why would hovering over the expression have to evaluate it again?  Surely if MS made this work, it would be a matter of displaying the already evaluated value.  This would avoid the overhead and potential side effects of evaluating the expression again.

Of course, it would be much better if the evaluated value displayed in the Locals window whenever a foreach loop is in progress....

Answer (score 9):

One option is to assign it to a temporary variable prior to your loop.

```
var items = someObject.GetItems( someParameter );
foreach ( var item in items ) {
    ...
}
```

This will allow you to inspect `items` directly.

> even though it was clearly computed and returned in order for the loop to be able to execute.

The problem is that this is not true.

If `GetItems` is an `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>`, it may not be evaluated.  The "collection" could, in fact, be an infinite enumerable.

Comment: While this is certainly true, I don't consider it a solution, since my question was specifically how to avoid doing this. Thanks tho.

Comment: @chaiguy: I was trying to show you why there isn't a direct way - the Watch can work in some cases, but can be potentially dangerous (as enumerating can have side effects) in others.

Comment: Actually, the expression will always have been evaluated, even if the full collection hasn't been calculated yet.  As such, it ought to be at least possible to see the result of this evaluation, even if said result is a lazy enumerable.

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Studio debugger does not have a feature for this unfortunately.

Notice that in the general case, it can’t. The collection could be an iterator block with complex computations; you wouldn’t want the debugger to evaluate it more often than the program would.

But of course there is the obvious workaround to store the collection in a variable:

```
var items = someObject.GetItems( someParameter );
foreach ( var item in items ) {
    ...
}
```

Now you can look at `items` in the debugger. Of course the same limitations apply — if it is a complex enumerable, the debugger won’t display a convenient list of items. But in the common cases (e.g. lists, arrays, etc.) it does.